# Why do we do type casting while creating driver object in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("url");
```

In above code, instead of giving `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` we used to give `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` (Means we are doing type casting). May I know why do we do this and what will happen in above code?

Answer (score 1):

First, you must understand, that by casting you are not actually changing the object itself, you are just labeling it differently. 
In this case, you create a ChromeDriver and upcast it to WebDriver, then the object doesn't stop from being a ChromeDriver. It's still a ChromeDriver, but it's just treated as any other WebDriver and its ChromeDriver properties are hidden until it's downcasted to a ChromeDriver again.

This concept comes under loose coupling so that there are no dependencies of intermediate classes.

For example: -

```
Animal a = new Dog();
Dog d = new Labrador();
```

so we can also write

```
Animal a = new Labrador();
```

So their is less dependencies of `Dog` class over here.

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion it is useful to use each specific driver capability without change how we call the driver. For example:

Test case 1:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions",
            "--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view", "test-type");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
capabilities.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1);
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Test case 2:

```
SafariOptions safariOpts = new SafariOptions();
safariOpts.setUseCleanSession(true);
safariOpts.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
cap.setCapability(SafariOptions.CAPABILITY, safariOpts);
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, "dismiss");
cap.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1); // 0- from Top,
    // 1 - from
    // bottom
cap.setBrowserName("safari technology preview");
cap.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
driver = new SafariDriver(cap);
```

If you made a class with a selectable driver, you could have the same code for all the browser. And you could execute the same test cases between different browser with only one development.